# Remove carriage returns and newline feeds from Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm having some issues replacing newline feeds and carriage returns in my Python script and I have tried numerous ways to do it but to no avail. I have tried the different solutions from StackOverflow but nothing seems to be working.

Example of the inputted JSON file:

```
"isActive" : true, 
            "Level" : 4, 
            "actions" : [
                {
                    "isActive" : true, 
                    "description" : "Alert escalation for handover delays. \r\n"
                }, 
                {
                    "isActive" : true, 
                    "description" : "Notify Director \r\n"
                }
```

This is currently how i'm doing it:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
import pandas as pd
from azure.storage.filedatalake import DataLakeServiceClient
from azure.core._match_conditions import MatchConditions
from azure.storage.filedatalake._models import ContentSettings
from pandas import json_normalize
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

mongo_client = MongoClient("XXXX") 
db = mongo_client.scale_db 
table = db.scaling

document = table.find()
docs = list(document)
docs = json_normalize(docs) 
docs.replace(r"\n",'').replace(r"\r",'').replace(r"\r\n",'')
```

Yet, i'm still seeing them within some strings:

```
17,False,1029,[6104],6,"[{'isActive': True, 'pressureLevel': 2, 'actions': [{'isActive': True, 'description': 'Team manager to review caseload during Wash up and with site matrons\r\n'}
```

Am I doing something wrong or is there something i'm missing out?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried without using raw strings (like `docs.replace("\n", '')`)?

Comment: can you add how the input looks like such that the issue can be replicated?

Comment: i've added the full python script for a better understanding

Comment: @lpeak yes i've also tried it without using raw strings

Answer (score 0):

Remember to capture the output

```
docs = docs.replace(r"\n",'').replace(r"\r",'').replace(r"\r\n",'')
```

Comment: that's what I wrote in my original script and it didn't work